# Como traduzir ia + GERUNDIO para inglês

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês

Estou lendo sobre a colocação dos pronomes oblíquos nas locuções verbais [aqui](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal-proclise-mesoclise-enclise/), e li as frases:

> Ia-lhe dizendo o que aconteceu.

É possível traduzir esta frase para inglês? 
Qual seria a diferença entre ela e

> Ia-lhe dizer o que aconteceu.

Comment: Você quer respostas só em português do Brasil? Ou também está interessado em português de Portugal? Em Portugal, as frases são muito diferentes; mas creio que no Brasil não.

Comment: Eu seria (estaria?) muito grato por respostas sobre português de Portugal também.

Comment: («Ficaria muito grato», como "I would become very grateful".) Ok, então se tiver tempo vou ver se respondo com a versão portuguesa. :)

Comment: @ANeves - No Brasil essas frases são diferentes, embora eu não saiba se a diferença é a mesma que existe em Portugal. No Brasil a segunda frase implica intencionalidade, enquanto a primeira a exclui: *Ia contando o segredo a ela, quando percebi que ela não era iniciada*. *Ia contar o segredo a ela, quando o José apareceu e tive de me calar*.

Comment: Eu sei que é a regra, mas a grafia "ia-lhe contar" me irrita profundamente. Afinal, eu não ia a ela para contar, eu ia contar para ela, portanto o pronome se vincula ao verbo principal, não ao auxiliar. Qual a razão por que se consagrou como norma algo tão contra-intuitivo (e impopular)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo menos em Portugal, as frases têm significados diferentes.
A primeira pode até ter duas interpretações diferentes, dependendo do contexto.

## Interpretação

A primeira frase, `Ia-lhe dizendo o que aconteceu.`, pode ter dois sentidos:

1. «Quase lhe dizia o que aconteceu» / «Quase que lhe contei o que se passou.» - este sentido tem uma conotação de algo que *acidentalmente* quase foi feito.
2. «Foi-lhe dizendo o que aconteceu» - este sentido tem uma noção de ato continuado.

A segunda, `Ia-lhe dizer o que aconteceu.`, tem outro sentido diferente:

3. «Estava prestes a contar-lhe o que aconteceu» - pretérito perfeito de contar, tem o sentido de "vou-te dizer o que aconteceu", mas no passado.

## Tradução

Eu traduziria estas 3 interpretações assim:

1. I almost told her what happened.
2. I was telling her what happened.
3. I was going to tell her what happened.

Comment: What about "Fomos de trem, eu e Fernanda, e eu fui lhe contando tudo o que havia acontecido durante a viajem".  Would you translate as "and I told her everything...."?

Comment: @Centaurus hmm... maybe, yes. :( But that translation loses some of the meaning, the part of gradually telling it: the translation back to Portuguese would be "fomos de trem, eu e a Fernanda, e eu contei-lhe tudo o que aconteceu durante a viagem". I will consider this, but I feel that your comment is important to include in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It loses the part of gradually telling it. I wonder if someone could come up with a better translation.

Answer (score 4):

Em Português de Portugal o gerúndio é por vezes utilizado para dar a entender uma certa duração, ou de um processo que está ainda a decorrer.

Dessa forma eu traduziria a primeira frase para o Inglês

> Ia-lhe dizendo o que aconteceu.

como "*I was* [in the process of] *telling her what happened*"

enquanto que a segunda frase

> Ia-lhe dizer o que aconteceu.

como "*I was going to tell her what happened*" mais num sentido de "*I was about to tell her what happened*"